# Error execution postgresql function under spring-data

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to implement search by inner json field.
My entity looks like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurants")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Restaurant extends BaseEntity {
    @Convert(converter = AddressConverter.class)
    private Address           address;
}
```

The address itself has city field inside.
Now i'm trying to create specification:

```
(root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(
                criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String.class, root.get("address"),
                                         criteriaBuilder.literal("city")), value)
```

And this is the error i have:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function jsonb_extract_path_text(character varying, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 420
```

I read the postgres docs and the arguments for function ara json and array of texts:

```
json_extract_path_text(from_json json, VARIADIC path_elems text[])
```

Meanwhile in my case both arguments are character varying. What i'm doing wrong? Is there a way to cast the first argument into json object?
I'm using latest postgresql 13.

Comment: Same thing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71293464/spring-data-jpa-with-specification-postgres-native-function-not-found please let us know if you end up with a solution