# Spring Data JPA with specification: postgres native function not found

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, predicate

I've been trying to dynamically use a PostgreSQL 13 native query:

```
public interface TasksRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Task> {
}

@AllArgsConstructor
public class TaskSpecification implements Specification<Task> {
    private final String entityCode;
    private final UUID entityId;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Task> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
// see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html
// jsonb_path_exists ( target jsonb, path jsonpath [, vars jsonb [, silent boolean ]] ) → boolean

        String template = "$[*] ? (@.entityCode == $code && @.entityId == $id)";
        String variable = "{\"code\":\"?1\", \"id\":\"?2\"}"
                .replace("?1", this.entityCode)
                .replace("?2", this.entityId.toString());
        return builder.isTrue(
                builder.function("jsonb_path_exists", Boolean.class,
/* target */            root.<List<RelatedEntity>>get("taskTags"),
/* path */              builder.literal("'" + template + "'::jsonpath"), //DEBUG CAST
/* vars */              builder.literal("'" + variable + "'::jsonb"),    //DEBUG CAST
/* silent */            builder.literal(Boolean.FALSE)
                ));
    }
}
```

But ended up with traumatic errors, despite my casting attempt:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    task0_.id as id1_0_,
    task0_.business_unit as business2_0_,
    task0_.due_date as due_date3_0_,
    task0_.is_urgent as is_urgen4_0_,
    task0_.task_tags as task_tag5_0_,
    task0_.task_text as task_tex6_0_,
    task0_.task_type as task_typ7_0_ 
from
    tasks_table task0_ 
where
    jsonb_path_exists(task0_.task_tags,?,?,?)=true

binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - ['$[*] ? (@.entityCode == $code && @.entityId == $id)'::jsonpath]
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - ['{"code":"ETY", "id":"bedb1903-3827-4507-883b-d41888d2ed68"}'::jsonb]
binding parameter [3] as [BOOLEAN] - [false]
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
ERROR: function jsonb_path_exists(jsonb, character varying, character varying, boolean) does not exist
Indice : No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I've tried to cast the above inner query parameters, but I suspect that this is a JPA-level issue; but I couldn't find the corresponding types to cast (jsonpath, jsonb) in my dependencies for them to applied with builder/Expression#as

Maybe the function is not visible (with schema issue or something alike?)

Thanks for any help

Comment: NB: this a workaround trial for a previous issue; please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71267707/spring-data-jpa-native-query-parameters-omitted-parameters

Comment: Did you found working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the cast `::jsonpath` and give it a try.
A json path is not a data type, so no need for the cast. Instead this part `root.<List<RelatedEntity>>get("taskTags")` shoud be a valid json object, I am not sure how this is rendered in the query.

To verify what is rendered and the values binded to the query, enable logging for hibernate as such in application.properties;

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace
```

This will show you the query and the value passed in the query.

Comment: Thanks @atish-s - my traces were already detailed, but the casting was added after the problem occurred and had no effect indeed